# MS Access String Replacement Query

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have 2 tables, `Table1` and `Table2`. I need to replace a string or a series of strings (separated by commas) in `Table1` referred from `Table2`.

I did a query on this but no luck:

```sql
TableNew: Iif(Instr([Table1.ColumnX1],[Table2.ColumnY1],Replace([Table1.ColumnX1],[Table2.ColumnY1],[Table2.ColumnY2]),[Table1.ColumnX1])
```

What i wanted to achieve was like this, in `Table1` `ColumnX1` there is:

```
A,B,C,1,2,3,4,D,E,F,5,6
```

Then in `Table2` I have:

```
+----------+-----------+
| ColumnY1 |  ColumnY2 |
+----------+-----------+
| A        | Z         |
| B        | Y         |
| C        | X         |
| D        | W         |
| E        | V         |
| F        | U         |
+----------+-----------+
```

After running that Query, it would result to

```
Z,Y,X,1,2,3,4,W,V,U,5,6
```

I would like this to run in each row available in `Table1`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a query such as the following to modify the values held by `Table1`:

```sql
update table1 inner join table2 on instr(1, table1.columnx1, table2.columny1) > 0
set table1.columnx1 = replace(table1.columnx1, table2.columny1, table2.columny2)
```

Note that the joins implemented in the above query cannot be displayed by the MS Access query designer, however, it is valid SQL which may be successfully executed by the JET database engine used by MS Access.